# How to fix my old theme so it loads jQuery properly

Tags: jquery, hooks

I have an older theme that is loading jQuery 'manually', and this conflicts with all plugins that are trying to use jQuery.
The following lines are included in the theme header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery.inputs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery.scrollpane.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/functions.js"></script>
```

I understand that I'm supposed to call a native WordPress hook to load these files, but I don't know the exact steps to do this. Can you help? Sorry for my noobiness.

Comment: jQuery is currently on ver 1.7, you should consider using the latest version.

Comment: What Theme are you currently using? Knowing the Theme will help us find the Theme's template/functional files, and will facilitate more accurate answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking a stab at a general answer, since we don't (yet?) have access to the specific Theme.

**Note: all of these edits can - and perhaps *should* - be implemented via Child Theme.**

First, you need to remove ALL of those lines from `header.php`. Scripts should be *enqueued*, rather than *hard-coded* into the template.

Then, you need to add the following to `functions.php`:

```
<?php
function wpse35169_enqueue_scripts() {
    // Enqueue WP-core bundled scripts
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'swfobject' );
    // Enqueue custom scripts
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-inputs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.inputs.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-scrollpane', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.scrollpane.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-mousewheel', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.mousewheel.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-easing', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-lightbox', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wpse35169-functions', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/functions.js' );
}
// Hook into 'wp_enqueue_scripts'
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse35169_enqueue_scripts' );
?>
```

If you need a specific dependency/load order for lightbox or functions.js, just add the appropriate `$deps` array to the [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) call.

That *should* resolve your issue - but again, without knowing what Theme you're using, I can't be 100% certain.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to your functions.php for each script:

```
wp_enqueue_script('handle',  get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory').'/path/to/script.js', array('dependencies'));
```

for instance:

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery',  get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory').'/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js');
```

Dependencies is only for scripts that depend on other script(s) - so you'd fill in 'jquery' for all scripts that need jQuery.

Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Comment: This answer could be improved. For "unregistered" scripts, you need to register (wp_register_script) and then enqueue the script (wp_enqueue_script). You can do both at the same time with wp_enqueue_script, which is what your example shows, but WordPress already registers jQuery, so you should NOT try to simultaneously register it as you have done. Just use: wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); That way, when WP is upgraded, the theme will automatically use the latest jQuery script included with WP and not the possibly old version you reference.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Google's copy of jquery instead of the bundled wordpress versions. The primary advantage being that most sites out there use google code so your users wouldn't have to load another copy of jquery since they could just use the cached script.

```
    // Load jQuery
   if ( !is_admin() ) {
      wp_deregister_script('jquery');
      wp_register_script('jquery', ("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"), false);
      wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

}
```

From there I would enqueue your custom scripts as suggested by Chip.

Answer (score 0):

Fun new way to register and enqueue your theme scripts.  Also makes it a little easier to add and remove new scripts when needed.

```
/**
 *  Registers javascript using wp_register_script
 *
 * '$handle' => array(
 * 'remote'  => boolean (true|false),   //optional default false 
 * 'src'     => 'file_name.js',         //string required
 * 'deps'    => 'dependencies',         //string optional 
 * 'footer'  => boolean (true|false)    //optional default false
 */

function scripts() {    
$deregister = array(
    'jquery' => array() 
);
$scripts = array(       
    'jquery'    => array(
        'remote'    => true,
        'src'       => 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js',
        'deps'      => null,        
        ),
     'jquery.cycle' => array(
         'remote'   => false,
         'src'      => 'jquery-cycle/jquery.cycle.min.js',
         'deps'     => 'jquery'
     ),
     'jquery.jcarousel' => array(
         'remote'   => false,
         'src'      => 'jquery.jcarousel.min.js',
         'deps'     =>  'jquery'
     ),     
    'functions' => array(
        'src'       => 'functions.js',
        'deps'      => 'jquery',
        'footer'    => true,
        )
);  
foreach ( $deregister as $key => $handle ) :
    if ( ! is_admin() ) :
        wp_deregister_script( $key );   
    endif;      
endforeach;

foreach ( $scripts as $key => $value ) :

if ( is_admin() ) return;

  if ( is_array( $value ) && array_key_exists( 'src', $value ) ) :

    $src = !empty( $value[ 'remote' ] ) ? $value[ 'src' ] : THEME_JS_URI . $value[ 'src' ];

        if ( ! $value['deps'] == null ) :
            wp_register_script( $key, $src, $value[ 'deps' ], false, !empty( $value[ 'footer' ] ) );

        else : wp_register_script( $key, $src, false, !empty( $value[ 'footer' ] ) );
    endif;     
        else : wp_register_script( $key, THEME_JS_URI . $src, $value, false );

  endif;

    wp_enqueue_script( $key );

endforeach;

 }
```